# How to prove the double inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Show that
$$\frac{-1}{x+1} \leq \int_{x}^{x+1} \frac{\sin{t}}{t} \, dt \leq \frac{1}{x}$$
Note that $\forall x >0$

Answer (score 3):

Hints:

1. $-1 \le \sin t \le 1$ for all $t$
2. $\dfrac{1}{x+1} \le \dfrac 1t \le \dfrac 1x$ for all $t \in [x,x+1]$.
3. $\displaystyle \int_{x}^{x+1} \, dt = 1$.